# any Idea on how to use https://sentry.io/for/c-plus-plus/ in VisualStudio C++ project?

Tags: sentry

any Idea on how to use https://sentry.io/for/c-plus-plus/ in VisualStudio C++ project ?

Answer (score 0):

There are installation steps on the documentation: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/native/

You also get a guide when you create a new project in Sentry